# How to find the variation of a vector measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a finite measure space and let $X$ be a Banach space. Let  $g:\Omega \to X$ be a Bochner integrable function and let $G:\Sigma \to X$ be a vector measure defined
by $G (E)=\int\limits_E g d\mu$. How to show that the variation function of  $G$ is given by  $|G|(E)=\int\limits _E \|g\|d\mu$? Of course it can easily be shown that  $|G|(E)\leq \int\limits _E \|g\|d\mu$.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The proof in Diestel and Uhl's *Vector Measures* starts with a sequence $(g_n)$ of simple functions such that $\int\Vert g_n-g\Vert\rightarrow0$. Then it is shown $|| G|(E) -\int_E\Vert g_n\Vert|\rightarrow0$.

Comment: This is done by choosing, for a fixed $n$ with $\int\Vert g-g_n\Vert<\epsilon$, a partition $\pi$ of $E$ such that both $$\sum_{A\in\pi}\Bigl \Vert \int_A g_n\Bigr\Vert =\int_E\Vert g_n\Vert$$ and $$|G|(E)-\sum_{B\in\pi}\Bigl\Vert \int_B g\Bigr\Vert<\epsilon.$$